# PHP - Foreach look giving a warning

Tags: php

I made a login page and while navigating from one page to another I'd like to destroy the unnecessary sessions

```
$keepSessions = array('vendor_id','email_login','user_password','passport_id');
    foreach($_SESSION as $sessionKey){
        if (!in_array($sessionKey,$keepSessions)) {
            unset($_SESSION[$sessionKey]);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I get the following error PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type in unset

I cannot seem to find a solution that uses the foreach and $_SESSION to elimate the above error

Comment: Are you add `session_start()` in the page and print the `$_SESSION`

Comment: Use `array_keys($_SESSION) as` ...

Comment: @TamilSelvan Yes. I am. It is included further above.

Comment: was is inside $_SESSION? do you have any arrays stored in there? because if so, you'll be using that array as a key in the unset call.

Answer (score 3):

```
$keepSessions = array('vendor_id','email_login','user_password','passport_id');
foreach($_SESSION as $sessionKey => $sessionValue){
    if (!in_array($sessionKey,$keepSessions)) {
        unset($_SESSION[$sessionKey]);
    }
}
```

Seems you were using the values inside the $_SESSION variable instead of the keys. Hope it helps!

Comment: i would also add an `isset()` before `in_array()` (merging with &&) just for security reasons...

Comment: @UnskilledFreak that won't be needed. foreach will only loop over what is already set

Comment: i also got such an scenario and got some errors while parsing the session like this, reason was an XSS session bug that injects pure unclear things to the session, also adding or deleting vars in there while parsing the session - but if this app is secure - i've newer said a word :)